# Change subject line in new Gmail compose window

Tags: gmail

With the old compose format, there is a section to edit the subject line.
However, I'm not seeing this with the new compose window - am I missing something?

[image: old vs new compose]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Click the down arrow next to the reply arrow (upper left corner). That'll give you the option to (additionally) *Forward*, *Reply all* (not pictured), or *Edit subject*.

[image: screen shot]