# Editing Subject in new Gmail

Tags: gmail

For [Change subject line in new Gmail compose window](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40153/change-subject-line-in-new-gmail-compose-window), the answer given on 7 Feb about how to edit the subject line in the new format of Gmail does not work for me.

There is no box on the left with a down arrow to options to reply, forward or edit subject in my version. There *is* a book on the *right* offering options to

- Reply
- Reply to all
- Forward
- Filter message
- Print
- Delete
- Report spam
- Report phising
- Show original
- Message text garbled
- Translate message
- Mark answered

**But**, no option to edit subject

Comment: Which question are you referring to?

Comment: You need to be replying to a message.

Comment: To edit inbox subject, use this plugin in Gmail website: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rename-email-subject-by-c/miepnlkmnjdfcnkplikgackpobfmaifb
(This could be an answer of the thread would not be protected)

Answer (score 20):

First, you hit the reply button (in the right, as you said)

[image]

Then, in the reply message composer, you'll have the left arrow. Click and you'll find the "edit subject" option.

[image]

Comment: I don't want to have to reply to edit the subject.