# Editing gmail subject line when replying or forwarding

Tags: gmail

I tried clicking on the drop-down arrow next to the reply arrow, as suggested in "[Editing Subject in new Gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/editing-subject-in-new-gmail?rq=1)", but "Edit Subject" is not among the choices.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: That's the way to do it and there's not another method within Gmail to use. Can you provide a screen shot?

Comment: See answer below but also, this video might be helpful:
https://youtu.be/zarFloHK-Is?t=66

Answer (score 22):

The process changed slightly when Google redid their compose message process.

Under the new process, when you click reply it will open a mini window at the bottom of the message for your to compose your reply.  At the top of the composing area will be the address to which you are sending the message, and to the left of that will be a different "reply" arrow, with the following options:

[image]

Select **Edit Subject** here and it will change to the full compose window, rather than the mini "inline" version at the bottom of the message.  From the full compose window you can change the subject line before sending.

Comment: This is the same answer as given to the question the OP says doesn't work, so this isn't terribly helpful. (Although the OP hasn't come through with the asked-for extra information, either.)

Comment: It seems that she is asking about the menu in the **reply** button, but the option is not there.  The link she gave to the duplicate question *does* explain where to find it, but if you get hung up on the first part of the answer, you may be misled.  I definitely agree with your request for screenshot though, because otherwise I think this is just a bit of confusion rather than an actual problem.

Comment: There are two different such dropdowns. One At the top of the message which allows you to select the actions: Reply, Forward, Filter, Print, Delete, Report etc. The other is more in the middle (but at top of composing area as mentioned), and has the option to "Edit Subject". As mentioned it is to the Left of "Recipients". It is not obvious or easy to find among the multiple arrows and dropdowns you will see and it doesn't always appear as pictured above (depends on whether you are forwarding, replying etc)