# Editing subject line in Gmail

Tags: gmail

How to edit the subject line of a message in Gmail? When clicking the return/down arrow I get a list of options as the following:

- reply
- reply to all
- forward
- filter messages like this
- print
- delete this message
- report spam
- show original (that is all the coding)
- message text garbled?
- translate message
- mark as unread

Answer (score 4):

You can't edit an existing message, including subject line. All you can do is [change the subject line when responding to a message](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/40153/354). (This would spin off a new conversation thread.)

I do know that some third-party email clients will allow you to edit messages. You could always try using one of those, downloading your email, edit the messages you want, then re-upload them (or just use IMAP), but you'd probably end up with two separate messages and such things are beyond the ken of this site.